# Open mapping theorem for holomorphic functions from corresponding statement about harmonic functions

Tags: complex-analysis, multivariable-calculus, reference-request, open-map

Let $f := u + iv : \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ be a complex analytic (holomorphic) function. We know that $u, v : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ are individually open maps. I was wondering whether one can conclude the fact that $f$ is an open map from the corresponding properties of $u, v$.

There seem to be many theorems in complex analysis books which are not actually complex analytic in nature (like the maximum principle, mean value property and several others). When I say not "complex analytic in nature", I mean that the proofs do not use the complex structure of $\mathbb{R}^2$. So I am trying to understand whether the open mapping theorem of complex analysis is actually complex analytic in nature. Sorry if the question is too basic.

Comment: Note that in general if $u, v : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ are open maps it doesn't follow that $u+iv$ is (see $u(x,y)=v(x,y)=x$); you need to use that $u,v$ are harmonic conjugates somewhere - for example $(x,y) \to (u,v)$ is a local change of variables in the complex plane at any nonsingular point

Comment: @Conrad Yes, I am guessing that the CR equations should come in somewhere.

Comment: the CR equations imply that at any noncritical point, the Jacobian is positive so one can apply the usual theorem from calculus for maps from $\mathbb{R}^2$ into itself and conclude; at critical points which are isolated for non constant $f$ not sure if a real approach works though

Comment: @Conrad Yes, that is precisely what confuses me.